# WebRTC function Removestream don't launch event OnRemoveStream. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a problem with the function Removestream on the WebRTC API, which it says: It is called any time a MediaStream is removed by the remote peer. But not in my case. I have created peer connection like this:

```
var STUN_OR_TURN = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}; 
var pc_constraints = {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]};
    pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(STUN_OR_TURN, pc_constraints);
```

I add stream like this: 
    pc.addStream(localStream);

And i remove the remote stream in the client like this:

```
pc.removeStream(localStream);
```

The function onAddstream it is called correctly and the event is succesfully but not in the case of onRemovestream.

Do i have any error in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to renegotiate the peerConnection(offer and answer) to call onRemoveStream.

[Demo](http://webrtcondemandcall.appspot.com/)

Comment: It didn't work. On my renegotiate method i'm calling `this.pc.createOffer(...);` and it doesn't call `onRemoveStream(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Into class `Peer` you can store the `remoteMediaStream` of each instance, update it with `onAddStream(MediaStream coming)`.

Then on removing a peer you can call `mListner.onRemoveRemoteStream(peer.remoteMediastream);`. (or how you named the interface method to handle what's happening when you remove the stream)